# How to answer this question

Tags: past-tense, past-continuous

6. As soon as he …………….. (get) under the shower, the doorbell …………….. (ring)

i was thinking to use past continues on the 'ring' but he go to the shower first. so I though to use past continues on the 'get' but it doesn't seem right to me. can anyone help me explain which one is correct for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several tenses that could be used.  The simplest would be to assume that this is a past-tense narrative.  That is, it is part of a story told in the past tense.  These events would simply be past tense "got", and "rang".

It could be present tense (to say that this always happens, or as a present tense narrative)

And given the brain-dead nature of these tests they probably want you to use **past perfect** "had got(ten)" and **past* "rang".  But that is only because the person who writes this kind of test doesn't understand the past perfect.

Past continuous for an event like "get under the shower" would mean doing it repeatedly, under-out-under-out-under-out!

Comment: By "brain-dead"  I mean that most sentences, you can't work out the tense from the context.  So questions asking for the "correct" tense are nearly always unanswerable.

Comment: Well, I was getting under/in the shower when the bell rang. I only did it once, too, because when I answered the door they told me the house was on fire, so I never got back in the shower. Isn't that a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you get *in the shower*, not *under the shower*. [Edit: JamesK says that *under* is ok in BrE. I've never heard it used in AmE AFAIK.]

I would say this:

> As soon as he got in the shower, the doorbell rang.

Both things happened before *now*, so use the past for both.

You can use past continuous, and it might be the better choice. Set it up like this:

> He was getting in the shower when the doorbell rang.

Past continuous generally is used to place a past incident inside a range in which another incident occurred. The past incident is in simple past, with *when* or *while*.

> I was eating breakfast when the phone rang.
> While I was eating breakfast, the phone rang.

Present tense would be more for an ongoing situation:

> Every time I get in the shower, the doorbell rings.

Comment: Get under is fine, at least in BrE

Comment: @JamesK Interesting. Not so much in AmE.